# Firebase- How to retrieve specific set of data using angularfire

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I am very new to firebase, and angularfire, not able to find examples with **new** angularfire and firebase api, most of the examples used old apis,

firebase -3.2.0
angularfire -2.0.1

Here are two cases:

**Case 1:**

[image]

I want to retrieve only record having name:"amitabh"  with email and uid,

here is what I have done

```
function getUserName(uid){
 return firebaseDataService.users.startAt("amitabh")
   .endAt("amitabh")
   .once('value', function(snap) {
     console.log('matching name address', snap.val())
   });
```

}

but its returning whole users list,not that one particular record.

**Case 2:**

[image: ![enter image description here]

How to retrive only **name** form the above database using angularfire new api.

```
ref=firebase.database().ref();
$scope.user=$firebaseArray(ref.child('users'));
```

in html

```
{{user.name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
var id= 'LnsdgmDFX6WJi13B32abj5ah60O2';
var ref = firebase.database().ref('/users/').child(id);
$scope.user= $firebaseArray(ref);
```

and in your HTML

```
 <li ng-repeat="user in user">
 {{user.name}}
 </li>
```

Comment: I edited the picture, previous picture was uploaded by mistake, sorry for that, Please check Case 2 now.